# Clear function implementation for Single Linked List

Tags: java, data-structures

I am writing a clear function for my SingleLinkedList implementation.

```
  /*
 * Take the next node in some temp variable
 * free the current node
 * after freeing the current node, go to the next node with temp variable
 * repeat this process for all nodes
 */
public void clear() {
    if ( head == null ) {
        return;
    }

    SListNode current = head;
    while ( current._next != null ) {
        SListNode temp = current._next;
        current._data = 0;
        current._next = null;
        current = temp;
    }

    current._data = 0;
    head = null;
    size = 0;
}
```

The SingleLinkedList class has:

```
public class SingleLinkedList {
   private SListNode head;
   private int size;
... various member functions
}
```

where SListNode has:

```
public class SListNode {
   int _data;
   SListNode _next;
}
```

Checked the implementation of deleteList function in:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-function-to-delete-a-linked-list/

I think the deleteList function is making the head point to null, while all other linked nodes should still be pointing to other links which may impede the gc to not pick them up for cleanup.

Question is: Is the way I have indicated (clear fn) a better solution than the one indicated in the site above (deleteList) ?

Comment: If you add all nodes as next node the last, there would be any dangling pointer

Answer (score 0):

In Java dangling pointers cannot occur because there is no mechanism to explicitly deallocate memory. Rather, the garbage collector may deallocate memory, but only when the object is no longer reachable from any references.